# Too much of virtual/abstract static property/method questions

Tags: discussion

I just posted a new answer of an about 5-years old-question I've ever answered:

1. *[How to implement virtual static properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346631/how-to-implement-virtual-static-properties/48177666#48177666)*

And I noticed there are a bunch of similar questions:

1. *[Can't define static methods in abstract types. How to work arround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801218/cant-define-static-methods-in-abstract-types-how-to-work-arround)*
2. *[Why can't I have abstract static methods in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284/why-cant-i-have-abstract-static-methods-in-c)*
3. *[Can't define static abstract string property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567569/cant-define-static-abstract-string-property)*
4. *[C# virtual static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243836/c-sharp-virtual-static-method)*
5. *[Why can't I declare C# methods virtual and static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248263/why-cant-i-declare-c-sharp-methods-virtual-and-static)*
6. *[C#, implement 'static abstract' like methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823665/c-implement-static-abstract-like-methods)*
7. *[C# virtual (or abstract) static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763344/c-sharp-virtual-or-abstract-static-methods/763364#763364)*

For those who are not familiar with the C# language, here's a little brief explanation:

- *virtual/abstract* both mean *overridable* with non-static classes where *virtual* can reside within non-abstract classes while *abstract* can't. Besides, *abstract* is a requirement while *virtual* is optional for override.
- Properties in C# are essentially a setter/getter or a pair of these accessor methods with invisible compiler-generated name prefixed with `set_`/`get_`, e.g., `get_TheseQuestionsMerged` or `set_ThemMarkedAsDuplicate`. That is, ask about the *modifiers* on the properties or methods is fundamentally the same thing.

However, none of these question is marked as duplicate. And most of them are answered like *No, you can't* or *It can't be*...

So I'm super curious: Why are they not marked as duplicate? Are there some kind of FAQ category as a handy reference for the users before who attempt to ask it again in the future?

Comment: "why they are not marked as duplicate?" Because no one has gone about voting to close them as such yet. It requires 5 close voters to agree that the question should be closed.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I've flagged some if not all. The problem now is which is duplicate to which ..

Comment: Well... that is something you should have determined prior to flagging. Please tell me you didn't use the "In need of moderator attention" custom flag option, and instead used the appropriate Flagging > Should be closed > Duplicate option.

Comment: Keep in mind that once you've flagged for closure, the posts must go through the close vote review queue which usually has ~10 thousand review tasks pending.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I picked the `a duplicate... ` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be an useful cleanup task.

I think you can find the best question, and vote the others to close as its dupes. From that, the community will decide.

Choose the best one not only on the quality of the question, but consider also the quality of the answers.

You may also vote for the bad/good posts accordingly. If you see any improvable in the posts, you could improve it (spelling, tagging).

Later you could hunt for similar posts and close all of them as dupes.

Comment: I would also see the view count and the score of the questions and the answers. It is a subjective, balancing thing in my opinion.

Comment: @KenKin Uhm, I only see now that you have not 3k yet :-) You will have, soon. Sad for such many bounties, you could be nearly a 10k user now...

Comment: @peterh: crossing the 10K threshold is not all flowers and sunshine. It gives you instant X-Ray vision into the dregs of questions and answers that a lower rep mercifully hides. And *there is no preference* to turn it off; you must drop below 10K again.

Comment: @usr2564301 My total rep is around 32000, but I have no 10k account :-) But I've always estimated that the 10k is a false privilege, selling the recycle bin as the highest privilege shows for me the excellent sales skills of the top-top decision makers :-)